# Custom error page failed to load after editing htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I edited my htaccess file to rewrite `mysite.com/page` to `mysite.com/page.php` and to show 404 error page if a user requested `mysite.com/page.php` instead of `mysite.com/page`

I also added my own custom 404 error page

But when I requested `mysite.com/page.php`, the error page shown was Apache default 404 error page (instead of my custom error page), with additional error info:

```
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My error log:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
```

I have tried changing 404 at the last line above to 404.php but the custom error page still not showing up..

However, the custom error page did show up when I requested `mysite.com/page/` (notice the slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand, where this error comes from. But you can resolve it by exiting the rule chain when `404.php` is requested. Insert this rule at the beginning

```
RewriteRule ^error/404.php$ - [L]
```

---

Unrelated, but you can simplify your rules a little bit

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: The rule chain exit solution works well. Also I can now append '/' to the request so `mysite.com/index/` does not throw error page, and makes the URL neater

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
```

Comment: It does not work. Still got no error when requesting with .php

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code? This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.